# Javascript doesnt react

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do this:

```
$('form#jatak a.BigYellowtwo').click(function() {
    $('#undertekst').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

on this: please be aware that `#undertekst` is visible at this moment I try to click on `BigYellowtwo`.

```
<form id="jatak" method="post" name="jatak">
    <input class="Email" id="Email" name="Email" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Email'; }" onfocus=
    "if(this.value == 'Email') { this.value = ''; }" type="text" value="Email"><a class="BigYellow" href="#">Jeg er skarp!</a><br>
    <br>
    <div id="undertekst" style="display:none;">
        Ved at tykke JA TAK, vil du modtage en mail med mere information.
    </div>
</form>
```

I have no idea why its not working, i have tried several things, but with no output at all. And it seems like my experience stops me here....

Comment: The `a` inside `form#jatak` does not have *`.BigYellowtwo`*, but *`.BigYellow`* (judging from the provided snippet).

Comment: Your selector is `...a.BigYellowtwo...` but the element is `<a href="#" class="BigYellow">Jeg er...`

Comment: your div with id undertekst is not visiable as it has display:none how it can show you fadeOut(); you should use fadeIn() and the selector .BigYellowTwo is incorrect you should use .BigYellow

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry i forgot to tell, once i click the current a "BigYellow" the class changes to "BigYellowtwo" so i do have it there.

Also Ramzan once i click BigYellow it does fade in, but i cant seem to make it fade out by clicking BigYellowtwo

Comment: you should use fadeIn() instead of fadeOut()

Comment: No its already showed by some code i didnt show you guys, so its not hidden :) i need it to fadeOut

Answer (score 0):

First, your selector is wrong, there's no element with `BigYellowtwo` class. Instead, there is an anchor element with `BigYellow` css class. Second, element that you're trying to `fadeOut()` is already not visible - you've set `display: none` css attribute there. Here's working fiddle with bugs fixed: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yht6T/1/) and here's the code:

```
<form id="jatak" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" value="Email" class="Email" onfocus="if(this.value  == 'Email') { this.value = ''; } " onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Email'; } "><a href="#" class="BigYellow">Jeg er skarp!</a>
            </br></br><div id="undertekst">Ved at tykke JA TAK, vil du modtage en mail med mere information.</div>
        </form>
```

JS:

```
$('form#jatak a.BigYellow').click(function() {
    $('#undertekst').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Comment: see my comment at top :)

"Oh yeah, sorry i forgot to tell, once i click the current a "BigYellow" the class changes to "BigYellowtwo" so i do have it there. Also Ramzan once i click BigYellow it does fade in, but i cant seem to make it fade out by clicking BigYellowtwo"

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `display: none` style of your `#undertesk` div to show it by default.
And also you have made a typo, your link `ID` is `BigYellow` not `BigYellotwo`

**Here I fixed your code:** http://jsfiddle.net/w78t8/

I am posting it in the answer as well:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form#jatak a.BigYellow').click(function() {
    $('#undertekst').fadeOut('slow');
});
});
```

**EDIT:** If once clicked the class changes to `bigYellowTwo` then you are looking for `fadeIn()` and a live event checker (to match the changed element).

So add the following code:

```
$('form#jatak a.BigYellowtwo').live("click", function() {
    $('#undertekst').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: see my other comment please :)

Comment: wont work, i made a jsfiddle fo people to see: http://jsfiddle.net/7t7yX/ what im trying to do once clicking the a.BigYellowtwo is to submit my form, and run validateFields, this thing to fadeOut #undertekst is just to make it run, and then from there i knew i could submit, but yeah... I just need to submit my form once clicking BigYellowtwo, and then run validate fields

Answer (score 0):

try this one..

```
<form id="jatak" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" value="Email" class="Email" onfocus="if(this.value  == 'Email') { this.value = ''; } " onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Email'; } "><span class="BigYellow">Jeg er skarp!</span>
            </br></br><div id="undertekst" style="display:none;">Ved at tykke JA TAK, vil du modtage en mail med mere information.</div>
        </form>

$('.BigYellow').click(function() {
    $("#undertekst").show(100);
});
```

visit live demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/vW94y/

thank you..